# Docker containerization Deploy from Virtual Machine LAMP

Tags: linux, docker, containers, lamp, devops

I am new to Docker Containers, I have applications which are running on VM with LAMP stack, can any one guide me Am I use 4 separate containers 1)Linux
2)apache2
3)php
4)mysql or ? one single container , and please explain auto healing or expand with the resource

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 containers

1.Linux + apache + php

2. Mysql

note : each docker images will be having a OS(debian/ubuntu/alpine) with minimal package )
Because it will get easier to manage services. Make sure to mount volume of data_dir when running mysql as container as container dies you will loos all the data.
You may use docker-compose for managing services with linking between containers.
 * there are also many open-source platform which provides auto-healing and auto-scaling
 http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/